# Is there a way to get the regex that I am using to match 4 numbers only?

Tags: regex, regex-group

The issue I am having is that the Regex  I am using is matching more that the different variations of 8801. I need the regex to match 8801 only and not 01 and 108. The link below shows how the regex I am using is matching more than the desired 8801. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"\b[8]*(?:1[8]*[8]?0|0[8]*[8]?1)[8]*\b"
```

See [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S12H02/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(?=\d{4}\b)8*(?:18*0|08*1)8*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S12H02/2). Note that `[8]*[8]?` = `8*` (zero or more `8` chars) and `[8]` = `8` (the square brackets are redundant in this case).

The `(?=\d{4}\b)` positive lookahead requires four digits followed with a word boundary position immediately to the right of the current position.